# downloading multiple files from sftp

Tags: java, sftp

I am downloading this file from an SFTP server "ara22122013.txt", using the below code:

I want to download all the files in the server that has the string 22122013,

Here' example:

```
 Sring SFTPHOST = "10.10.10.10";
int    SFTPPORT = 22;
String SFTPUSER = "username";
String SFTPPASS = "password";
Session     session     = null;
Channel     channel     = null;
ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

JSch jsch = new JSch();

public void test()
{
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER,SFTPHOST,SFTPPORT);
            System.out.println("Checking username, host, and port...");
session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
System.out.println("Checking password...");
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();

config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

session.setConfig(config);

session.connect();
System.out.println("Session Connected");
channel = session.openChannel("sftp");

channel.connect();
System.out.println("Channel Connected");
channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;



                try {

                    channelSftp.get("ara22122013.txt", "C:/SFTP/" );
                } catch (SftpException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

        } catch (JSchException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

Please advise how?

Comment: I tried your command, but it is not downloading the file, and also it is not showing an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code. I hope this will help you.

```
 import java.nio.channels.Channel;
 import java.util.Vector;

 import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
 import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
 import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class SFTPJava {

/**
 * @param args
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String SFTPHOST = "10.20.30.40";
    int SFTPPORT = 22;
    String SFTPUSER = "USERNAME";
    String SFTPPASS = "PASSWORD";
    String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "/home/data/";

    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT);
        session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
        Vector filelist = channelSftp.ls(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
        for (int i = 0; i < filelist.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(filelist.get(i).toString());
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet:

```
Vector path = channelSftp.ls("C:/SFTP/" );

for(String s : path){
channelSftp.get(s, "C:/SFTP/" );
}
```

Please have a look to [channelSftp.ls()](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#ls%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I tried your code but the thing is that the program does not enter the for loop, please advise if you have another option.

Comment: Try now, and if it's not entering the for loop please debug it setting a breakpoint right after ls. Without log and/or more code I can't help you more.